# For every bounded, integrable function $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$, does there exist a non-zero continuous function $g$ such that $\int_{a}^{b} fg = 0$?

Tags: integration, analysis, definite-integrals

For every bounded, integrable function $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$, does there exist a non-zero continuous function $g$ such that $$\int_{a}^{b} fg  $$

is equal to $0$ (with $g \not\equiv 0$).

I found a neat solution for $f$ continuous: let $$g(x) = f(x)\cdot[f(a+b-x)]^2\cdot(2x-a+b).$$ By construction, this ensures that $fg$ is odd about the midpoint of the interval.

Comment: I will assume that $f$ is integrable in whatever sense you are considering. If $\int_{a}^{b}f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t=0$, then set $g(x)=1$. Otherwise, set $$g(x)=\left(\int_{a}^{b}f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\right)x-\left(\int_{a}^{b}tf(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\right). $$

Comment: Just boundedness is not enough. Existence of integrals would be a problem.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy It doesn't fit in the title but I have amended this in the main text.

Comment: For future reference, "non-trivial" is not standard jargon in this context. "Non-constant" or "non-zero" would be better terminology.

Comment: @SangchulLee Thank you. That was quick! Very elegant solution.

Comment: Can't you just pick any non constant $h(x)$ and $g(x) = h(x) - k$ and adjust $k$ as necessary?

Comment: @DanielV Yes, you are correct, I think. Indeed, Sangchul Lee's solution, which uses the special case $h(x) = x$, can easily be generalised to construct a solution for general $h(x)$. Admittedly, I didn't spend long thinking about this; I was just curious.